# EF Code-First Data Type Conflict between MySQL and Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, code-first

I using EF  code-first approach for tow databases engine (Oracle and MySQL).  but I have problem when declare property with decimal type then I cant apply database migration in oracle database because oracle doesn't have `Decimal` datatype. on the other hand when I add data annotation to obtain that is a `Number` type to be supported in oracle, it will not work in MySQL because it does not have `Number` data type

Please I advise how to solve this conflict

Comment: You need two migration projects and two DbContext configuration projects. It is by design.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv , yes I did that, but still I have the same entity class

Comment: Entities should be in separated project without any dependency to EF or at least to EFOracle and EFMySql.

Comment: Are you sure you need configuraton at all? Every database provider does (should) provide some default mapping for CLR types, including `decimal`. For instance, Oracle provider maps `decimal` to `number(18,2)` - see https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3/odpnt/EFCoreDataTypeMapping.html#GUID-484E9D3A-8E42-417F-9591-F2E7305E3F6A